# How do you specify that you do not want the default <br> created after a form tag Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now when I create a form using a `form_for` Ruby on Rails creates an extra `<br>` tag after the form.  Is there an option to not have RoR create this for me? Here is the code for creating the form:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => create_user_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/users" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="fsdfsdf+rgJKoc5sdQvsqvT2s=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" size="30" name="user[password_clear]" id="user_password_clear" class="text_box">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" size="30" name="user[password]" id="user_password" class="text_box">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="commit" class="button button_medium button_green">
  </div>
</form>
<br>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see any <br> at the end of the method source http://bit.ly/MfUc0p

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't plan on creating a new form you could refrain from closing the form until you want a 
 to appear, just don't add the <% end %> tag until you want a br and keep the following code inside the current form.
It's not very ellegant but it will probably work the way you want it to.